# Problem to acces admin of my site

Tags: users

I cannot acces admin of my website via Drupal.site.

I always have a screen saying "Drupal is under maintenance" but no login and password field.

Could anybody tell me how to access my site ?

Comment: Do you have terminal(ssh)  access to server?

Answer (score 0):

Type user/login in the URL (Drupal.site/user/login OR Drupal.site?q=user/login) to access Login page. 
Only site admin can login when the site is under maintainance mode.